# Foundation equalizer not working with vcards within a row?

Tags: javascript, html, zurb-foundation, equalizer

I am using Foundation as a backend for a website, and am attempting to use the equalizer function to keep a group of vcard divs at equal height.  My code is as follows:

```
<div class="row" data-equalizer>
  <div class="small-4 large-6 vcard columns" data-equalizer-watch>
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="small-4 large-6 vcard columns" data-equalizer-watch>
    ...
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

However, the equalizer function is not making all of these vcard divs equal.  So, what exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you add foundation js? and also are you add this code: '$(document).foundation();'

Answer (score 1):

Before you can use **Equalizer** you'll want to verify that `jQuery` and `foundation.js` are available on your page.

Just add `foundation.equalizer.js` AFTER the `foundation.js` file. Your markup should look something like this:

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.equalizer.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
```